# View Model Not Updating - Apply/Digest Already Running

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sweetalert

I have a strange issue, and I am hoping I am missing something obvious. "Sweet Alert" just pops a prettier angular modal - the `isConfimed` block executes when you click "Ok" on the modal.

Here is the problem - any code that I put in "isConfirmed" block EXECUTES - I can log it, etc, but it does NOT update the scope. For example, if I have $scope.test and change it in the block and then log it, the log will show it as changed, but the change won't be reflected on the UI. I tried apply/digest, but it tells me apply/digest is already running.

The funny thing is that the code runs perfectly (commented out example on bottom) when outside the block. What's funnier? The promise is there for testing - it doesn't help. I thought it wasn't seeing the scope, so I have tried broadcasting on rootScope, doesn't help either.

I am at a total loss.

EDIT: I just discovered that if I put the code in a timeout, it works. What the #@!@.

```js
$scope.showAlert = function(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    SweetAlert.swal({
            text: 'Warning, click ok or else!!!',
            otherSettings: 'blah blah blah',
            function(userClickedOk){
                if(userClickedOk) {
                    //this executes when I click "Ok on pop-up")
                    //Putting code here without a promise doesn't update view model either, promise didn't help.
                    deferred.resolve(true);
                    return deferred.promise;
                }
            }
        });

        deferred.promise.then(function() {
           //If I put doSomething() in $timeout, it works...
           $scope.doSomething();
        });
    });

//If I put doSomething() here instead of the promise, it works
//$scope.doSomething();
};
```

Comment: there's alot of problems with your syntax.. are those the actual codes?

Comment: I am not sure what you fixed, but I approved it since it doesn't look like anything changed. None of this is the "actual code" since the sweet alert settings take up a ton of space - the point is that the block runs, and it calls $scope methods, and they run, but they don't do what they normally do.

Comment: are you using just SweetAlert or [ngSweetAlert](https://github.com/jutaz/ngSweetAlertAsPromised) ?

Comment: ngSweetAlert. Btw, I appreciate you taking the time. Timeout "fixes" it. It's hilarious.

Comment: the event is outside of angular core....so you have to tell angular to run digest when scope is changed. `$timeout` will do that since it will call `$digest` internally

Comment: Why can't I force it with $digest(){//...my change}? Is there a cleaner way to do it than timeout?